# How to ignore changes in attribute order within .NET DataSet definition (XSD) when using SVN?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, tortoisesvn, dataset

I use TortoiseSVN for versioning of my large VB Project in Visual Studio 2008. Once in a while, when editing one of the many typed DataSets, VS feels like switching the position of the attributes `msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable`and `msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow` in like NINE THOUSAND places of the .xsd file. Sometimes I use a custom sed-script to reverse it again but most of the time I just commit it without knowing if there was any real change.

Can I prevent Visual Studio from messing with those attributes?
Can I enforce a specific ordering?
Or do I need some workflow within TSVN to ignore or revert such changes?

Added:
I wrote a small VB.Net Console app that scans thru the lines, sorting the attributes. It works on text alone as one cannot use xml parsing abilities without a massive increase in execution time and code size : (

I do hope someone knows a way around this stupidity or at least point me to some ready-to-use tool that can help here. If not, I have to `accept` my fate ^^

Answer (score 1):

I would add a process that order the file and call this process at each pre- or postbuild.
Then it should always create the same file even if the studio decide to change the file again.

The main problem is to write this tool and to know which elements should be sorted.

Your idea to revert it, could be simpler, if you write a tool which only compare the node elements of two files.

Comment: I concur, and if you're using TortoiseSVN this can also be done with [client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).